# Batch: replace string in file and filename with a loop

Tags: batch-file, replace

I have a text file with a name of the form

> text_j1.txt

The file includes multiple lines with the string *j1* at several places.

I would like to use this file as an input and then change the "*j1*" string with a loop from 1 to 500, so I would get 500 text files named `text_1.txt` to `text_500.txt`, and inside each text file all respective "j1"'s to be replaced with the corresponding number.

Is there a way to create a batch file to quickly do this automatically? I have found examples to replace stings in files or filenames, but not both and with changing numbers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

    set /a count=2

    :start

    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type text_j1.txt') do (
            set out=%%a
            set out=!out:j1=j%count%!
            echo !out!>>text_j%count%.txt
    )

    set /a count+=1

    if %count% lss 500 goto :start

    exit /b
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
for i in `seq 1 500`
do
    sed s/j1/$i/g < ext_j1.txt > ext_$i.txt
done
```